# trying to find page ID from page URL like https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=XXXXXX

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have URLs like this: https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=XXXXXX where XXXXXX is an ID, but not a page ID and I need to find the page ID from it.

I've tried requesting https://graph.facebook.com/XXXXXX?access_token=YYYY (where YYYY is an access token that have Page Public Content Access permission), but answer is Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'XXXXXX' does not exist...."

I found that Page ID is available in page source code of the web page, but Facebook disallow scrapping of their pages.

here are some examples:

https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100063722132763   => Page ID: 815246995503983
https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100063578267534   => Page ID: 330810097560194

So, if anyone know a way to find this Page ID from the URL using graph API (or any other way authorized by Facebook), I would be very thankfull!

Thank you,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

I find page ID in this way.

example page : https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100063722132763

I will keep 100063722132763 in front and find a post in this page.

post example : https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=pfbid01Focai6WiaWM6DR7oHaTQBmU7x9qzibJ5gjzfbsCTe9xqwjdQu2SiApP17BED1MEl&id=100063722132763

Combine 100063722132763 with story_fbid in pattern like this  100063722132763_pfbid01Focai6WiaWM6DR7oHaTQBmU7x9qzibJ5gjzfbsCTe9xqwjdQu2SiApP17BED1MEl and send in graph API you will get the postID with real page ID

[image]

I got a problem same as you. I hope anyone can find a easier way to solve this problem.

Comment: Now it is not working. The Page does not contain direct links to posts. Sadly